# List lettering and bulleting problems in iText in Java

Tags: java, list, itext

How come this works:

```
lA = new List(List.ORDERED, List.ALPHABETICAL); 
lA.setLowercase(List.LOWERCASE);
lA.setPostSymbol(") ");
```

but this doesn't:

```
lQL = new List(List.UNORDERED); 
lQL.setListSymbol("=");
lQL.setPostSymbol("  ");
```

?

In the first example in front of every item is "a) " or "b) " or "c) " etc...
In the second example in front of every item is only "=".

Before any ideas, two things. Firstly, I can't do it this way: `lQL.setListSymbol("=  ");`. I could explain it, but just go with it, it's simpler. Secondly, I tried setting second string to "k " (so it's not only spaces), but the output was still "="...

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have explicitly indicated that you want an *unordered* list with `List.UNORDERED`. Thus, you'll not get any order for your items, and therefore the post symbol will not be used.

From the documentation of `setPostSymbol`:

> Sets the String that has to be added **after a number or letter** in the
>   list symbol.

And from the source code of [`List`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/itextpdf/text/List.java.html):

```
  137       /**
  138        * In case you are using numbered/lettered lists, this String is added after the number/letter.
  139        * @since   iText 2.1.1
  140        */
  141       protected String postSymbol = ". ";
```

This number or letter will only be added for ordered lists, i.e., `List.ORDERED`. If you inspect the first argument of the constructor of `List`, you'll see that it receives a boolean to indicate if the list is numbered or not. Since you are passing it `List.UNORDERED`, whose value is `false`, you won't get a numbered list, and thus, `postSymbol` will not be appended.

Comment: Yeah, but why isn't the `List.setPostSymbol` showing? Is that `List.ORDERED` feature only or?

Comment: @Karlovsky120: Yes, indeed, it's the symbol that gets appended to the order, e.g. 1=, 2=. Since you have an unordered list, it doesn't get appended.

Comment: Thanks! *Meaningless text to pass the char limit.*

Answer (score 0):

To set or unset number ,letter or bullet use the following single code for List with usage of iText pdf out or simply with list.

For example,for List with no bullet or string or number usually required in printing bills.

```
List list = new List(false, false, 50);
list.setListSymbol(" ");
```

Thank you for your queries..